# Access denied running gpo logon batch script executing reg add/query

Tags: windows, scripting, batch

I am using MS Server 2012 R2 64bit with Active Directory installed. I want to execute a few batch scripts when the user logs into a computer. These scripts use the "reg add/query" commands to check if a registry key exists and if it doesn't it will create it and set a value to the new key.
The problem I'm having is that it seems that every time the scripts run when a user executes, the scripts attempt to execute the reg add/query commands and it gets an "access denied" message.
Here is a sample of my batch script:

```
reg query HKCU\Software\myownkey >null 2>&1

if %ERRORLEVEL%% NEQ 0 (
   echo myownkey doesn't exist. Must create it.
   reg add HKCU\Software /v myownkey /t REG_DWORD /f /d 1 >null 2>&1
)

PAUSE
```

When the user logs into the machine, the script is executed and then it pauses so I can see if the script executed properly or not. All I see is that it prints "Access Denied" every time it attempts to query/add the registry.

Any one knows how to solve this problem? Am I better off using powershell scripts instead and won't run into this problem?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Could you log in as one of the problem users and just double check the permissions on the HKCU\Software key?

Comment: Yes, I can log in as a domain user and each user does have access to the scripts and can execute them properly and it does work. That's what I don't understand as to why the logon GPO doesn't work. When using the logon GPO, the script is executed but I get access denied when attempting to read/write to the registry using the reg query/add command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not double `L` in `NUL`:

```
reg query HKCU\Software\myownkey >NUL 2>&1
```

`>null` attempts to redirect command output to a *file* named **`null`** in the current directory which is supposedly `C:\Windows` or `C:\Windows\system32`.

> [**nul**](http://ss64.com/nt/nul.html)
>
> The null device is a special file that discards all data written to
>   it, but reports that the write operation succeeded.
>
> It is often used to hide the output (or error output) of a command.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> SomeCommand >nul
> ```
>
> `Nul` provides no data to any process that reads from it (yielding
>   `EOF` immediately)
>
> For more examples see the [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) page.

Comment: You sir are amazing! Thank you so much for catching that error in my code. I was using null instead of nul because I was so used to using null in Linux that I just thought it was the same in Windows. Anyhow, I am very happy that you found a solution to my problem. Thank you again!